# sssd configuration problems in Ubuntu 19.10 - unlike Ubuntu <19.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, kerberos, sssd

sssd is not working correctly on Ubuntu 19.10. 
When trying older ubuntu versions (<19.04) with the same configuration of ldap.conf, sssd.conf and krb5.conf, authentication to LDAP works fine.

I'm using krb5 as authentication provider. 
When running kinit - ldapsearch works fine, so it has to be an issue with sssd. 
sssd service is active and is not reporting any errors.

Are there any major differences when configuring sssd on Ubuntu 19.10 compared to the previous Ubuntu releases?

Comment: I already went through the manpage and all logs and the config is being accepted by sssd. Thanks for the "nice" reminder but this is not helping me.

Comment: You asked a very generic question with no actual error message, no reproductible code/config, no detail about the Kerberos back-end, just _"SSSD does not work"_ -- did you really hope that someone could help? We have no divination powers... Show us some tangible facts.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19.10 uses sssd with version 2.2.0.
Given some logs I get an error 4 in libsss_proxy for the sssd backend.
I tried the same config files under Ubuntu 20.04 daily with the a newer version of sssd (2.2.2) and it works perfectly. Seems like sssd 2.2.0 in eoan is buggy.